# Group management from command line (probably not lusrmgr.msc)

Tags: batch-file, rdp, command-line-tool

I know how to manage groups (like RDP access) with "lusrmgr.msc"
How to do it with a command line? (or a short script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a French Windows 7, the answer is:

```
net localgroup "Utilisateurs du Bureau à distance"
net localgroup "Utilisateurs du Bureau à distance" /add mydomain\mylogin
net localgroup "Utilisateurs du Bureau à distance" /delete mydomain\mylogin
```